# C# (picturebox): Something similar to java's Graphics2d.translate?

Tags: java, c#, picturebox

I am trying to create a platformer game in C#

What I want is the player to be always centered in the picturebox, and the camera basically following the player around.

In order to have the camera follow the player, in java I can call

```
Graphics g = this.getBufferStrategy().getDrawGraphics();
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
double x = -Player.getX() + (Game.WIDTH / 2);
double y = -Player.getY() + (Game.HEIGHT / 3);
g2d.translate(x, y);
```

Is there a similar way to do that in C# picturebox?

Note: I have tried doing

```
    private void render (object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(0,0,50,50));

        g.TranslateTransform(x,y);
    }
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x = x + 50;
        y = y + 50;
    }
```

and the position doesnt seem to change on click (all events seem to work okay)

Edit: Turns out all I had to do was call g.TranslateTransform(x,y); before anything else. Thanks for the help!

Comment: See [`Graphics.TranslateTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.translatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I did try it, didnt work..maybe I am doing something wrong, check the edited question

Comment: You must apply transformation **before** calling drawing methods (`FillEllipse` in your case).

Comment: oh huh, that was simpler than i expected... Thank you!

Comment: @fanisdeligiannis As a little bit of advice, drawing graphics this way is very slow. You'd be a lot better off using a gaming framework like XNA or Unity for realtime gaming.

Comment: @LukeBriggs The reason I am trying to create my own platformer 2d engine is mainly for practice, thanks for the advice though

Comment: @fanisdeligiannis at which point I'd still recommend using DirectX / OpenGL (or SharpGL and SharpDX) as that's how "everybody else" does it :)

Comment: @LukeBriggs will check them out, thanks